# jsonb data type lookup cost in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

This might be an obvious and simple question.

But I read through the `jsonb` data type [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING), but nowhere it mentions the lookup cost of a key in jsonb data.

For example, let's say I have a table with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE A (id character varying (20),
                info jsonb);
```

I want to know how postgres would parse a where query as below:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE info->>'city' = 'portland';
```

While going through the jsonb field of a row, is the lookup constant time (`O(1)`) or linear time (checking each key one by one in the row's jsonb dictionary) within that jsonb data dictionary?

My intuition is that it must be constant time (else what's the point of a dictionary style data?) but I can't see it in the official documentation to convince my team.

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As with any `WHERE` condition in SQL: if there is no index, the database has to go through all rows of the table to find those that satisfy your condition.

You can either index a specific expression, or you can index the whole json value using a [GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) which then enables Postgres to use the index if any of the supported operators are used.

If you always check for the city, you can create a regular B-Tree index:

```
create index on a ( (info->>'city') );
```

If you don't know what you will be looking for, a GIN index might be a better choice:

```
create index on a using gin (info);
```

But you will need to change your query to use one of the operators that are supported by a GIN index, e.g. using the [contains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) operator `@>`

```
select *
from a 
where info @> '{"city": "portland"}::jsonb;
```

---

Note that an index lookup is not always the most efficient solution. Sometimes it's faster to simply go through all rows, sometimes the index lookup is faster.

If you want to learn more about indexes in relational database, go through the material here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: in the absence of any indexes over the jsonb data, when it is going through a particular row, does it also go through all the keys in the jsonb data? or is that lookup constant time (like in a dictionary)?

Comment: @pranav3688: well, [the manual  says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html): "*jsonb data is stored in a decomposed binary format that makes it [...] significantly faster to process, since no reparsing is needed*"  - so I guess there is some kind of lookup dictionary involved